# Forcing Object Data Source To Reinstantiate

Tags: mobile, xpages

I am using the XPages Mobile Controls with an Object data source (Java Class which is NOT a managed bean) tied to View scope on a second app page. I have resetContent on the second page set to true. So I would have assumed the Object Data Source would be destroyed and recreated every time I transitioned to the second page.

When I transition to the second page the first time, the createObject() method is invoked as expected. If I transition to the second page using a button AND set forceFullRefresh to true the createObject() method is invoked. If, however I have a Rounded List Item with a moveTo specified for the second page the createObject() method does not get invoked. Instead the object remains set to the last value it was using when that application page was last accessed.

Is there a way to force the createObject() method to be invoked every time I transition to the page?

Comment: "every time I transition to the page" - is your page part of mobile page within mobile application - meaning the same XPage, or do you use two different XPages?

Comment: I am using Xpages Mobile Controls.. i.e. these are Application Pages inside a Single Page Application.

Comment: That means, viewscope keeps your object. You should switch to request scope or to delete the object on some event. Script "variable = null" should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to move the object data source from view scope to request scope.  This is possible because I do not have the need for any partial refreshes on that page until the details are ready to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to call the *refresh* method of the datasource in SSJS.
Assumning you have only one datasource on the page, you can access the ObjectDataSource from the view:

```
var ods:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.ObjectDataSource = view.getData().get(0);
ods.refresh()
```

This executes the *createObject* method binding and reinstantiate the datasource.